# Firefox: Disabling exit alert boxes?

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox, watir

Is it possible to completely disable the JavaScript exit alert boxes that spring up when I try to leave the page?

I'm running Firewatir on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to use Greasemonkey scripts while using Firewatir?  If so, then the BlockUnloadEvents script might do the trick:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23865

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find some help here:

- http://github.com/bret/watir/blob/master/firewatir/unittests/javascript_test.rb
- http://github.com/bret/watir/tree/master/firewatir/unittests/
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Pop+Ups

If not, post the question at http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/